# How to Partially Allow LTR, RTL support in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

So in my recent interview I was asked what if within a `ConstraintLayout` which has multiple child `Views` supports part of the `Views` LTR and RTL change and part of the `Views` to ignore it. Like the images below:

[image]

As you can see, blue views change their direction based on Views' layout direction but the Red Green and Yellow ones keep there position relative to each other, but align their (collective) start and end based on the layout direction to different `View`.

I understand you can set up the blue `Views` simply by using start and end attributes instead of left and right. But how do you keep the order of the multicolored `Views` same but at the same time reposition them alongside other `Views`? While making sure there is no deeper hierarchy than the parent `ConstraintLayout`.

I realize I may not be making much sense here, I just can't think of another way to convey the question.

Comment: can't you just put a linear layout in that spot?

Comment: @JohnLord of course you can but as I said earlier this was an interview question and one of the constraints of was, you can't use increase the depth of the views' hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I don't know of any way to specify that part of a layout should remain *LTR* when all the other parts go *RTL*. I presume that you are looking for an XML-only solution.

Something to keep in mind is that the left-to-left, right-to-left constraints are still valid. Normally, these would just be replaced by start-to-start and end-to-start constraints. So, with this in mind and making some assumptions about the layout, the following works:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="239dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/box2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/box3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/box1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/box2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image][image]

There is one trick: `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle` has to be set on the first and last view in the horizontal chain. There is also a tendency for the designer to change the left/right attributes back to start/end.

IRL, I would just wrap the blocks in a view group and be done with it. I think that it would be easier to maintain and not be prone to break.

Comment: I think that's what he was looking for, although when I asked him he said something about ignore RTL attribute. Anyways I will accept the answer as correct as it clearly works. I agree there is a chance for left/right to be replaced by start/end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the multicolored views in single view and make that view as parent for your other view's constraints.

Comment: As I said in the question (or maybe I didn't make it clear enough), can't use another `ViewGroup` inside the `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I did this just by setting `layoutDirection` in root layout

```
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:elevation="2dp">
```